# openvpn client and server running on the same RPI

Tags: networking, vpn

Is it possible to have both the VPN client and server running on RPI? I'm currently running a openvpn server in my RPI. I'm able to connect to my openvpn server from mobile network. But I'm also running torrent client in RPI. So I thought of using a VPN client in RPI that uses PIA VPN service.

Does it make sense to have a VPN client and server, running on the same network( also on the same device -RPI)? Is it valid?

If it is possible to have both the VPN client and server running on RPI, can I make torrenting service alone to use the VPN client?

Answer (score 2):

You have openvn already running in `--mode server` on your Raspberry Pi. So it is no problem to start openvpn just as second process with `--client` option and connect to the other remote openvpn server. Haven't tried it but I don't see why it should not work. The only trouble I see is with routing. I think you will get two interfaces tun0 and tun1 and you have to route the different traffic to the right destination. It is just one command with `openvpn` and the right options. Try it.

Comment: The routing will be fine as long as you use different address ranges.